# SOA architecture. Best strategy to support versions

Tags: wcf, architecture, soa

He are having a debate about a proper way to support versions in SOA.

1. One option: is to implement all endpoints (Version/Contracts) in the same application in a strict manner. Thus supporting backward compatibility in the same application.
2. Second option: to create branches with single endpoint. Deploy each endpoint in a different application.

Each option has its pro/cons. Most of the sites I've notice support strategies in the same application (code base) strict/agile/flexible. 
But there are also benefits to the second options. By breaking the endpoint to branches and different deployments each endpoint become more stable and detached from the others. Allowing developers to not consider backward compatibility when they write new functionality. I guess it also makes the 3rd party integration harder (changes to DB scheme etc.).

What do you think?

Comment: I think the problem has been well-considered. https://resources.sei.cmu.edu/asset_files/TechnicalNote/2012_004_001_15356.pdf

Comment: I've read this article. It is a very good and informative. Some resolutions are in the service ALM. And they seem to support the first options with different strategies (Direct vs. Intermediate base). The do mention that backward compatibility with option 1 can be very expensive .I still couldn't find anywhere mention the second options. Which seems pretty solid to me.

Comment: I suppose if you're alright with the possible explosion of distributed versions, Option 2 is OK. I'd think that incurs too much maintenance, but perhaps not (pretty subjective). Unless each deployment is on its own DB (sounds like that's *not* the case) don't you have to deal with compatibility issues regardless? I suspect it's hard to avoid it, so why not keep the rest simpler? Or perhaps, you do a major release type of update (v.1.2.3.4 to v.2.0.0.0) *then* deploy a new instance but not for minor versions (v.1.3.4.5). Major versions suggest big changes and possible loss of compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely option 2!

To solve the DB issues you can use a repository for each micro service, and to avoid multiplicity, handle the generated ORM entities in a shred kernel.as i see it, the idea of a micro service is that it is a stand alone process, while if you go with the 1st approach you are coupling between services that are not related(NOT IN THE SAME DOMAIN => DDD) + the backward compatability issue, every time you want a fix you have to: or update all micro services, or ask the clients to update their side.

sincerely YBM

Comment: What about defects? You will have to fix them in all the branches. And redeploy them.
While in option 1 its a single fix and a single deploy.